# Neo4j can I sort the relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using the movie dataset, I'm doing a query:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)<-[r1:ACTED_IN|DIRECTED|PRODUCED]-(person:Person)
RETURN movie, r1, person
ORDER BY movie.title, person.name
```

This gives me what I want, almost. The movies are sorted and the actors are sorted. r1 contains a `String[] roles`. Is there a way to return that sorted as well?

EDIT 2:

I don't want to update the storage, I'm approaching this as I am a customer with no control over the data.

The second example seems to not be combining the data correctly, but I tried it in my app anyways to see if it was viable and it doesn't bind, I think Spring still isn't recognizing the entity type.

The virtual relationship one looks promising, but I get a syntax error on a direct c&p:

```
Unknown function 'apoc.create.vRelationship' (line 11, column 23 (offset: 361))
"RETURN movie, person, apoc.create.vRelationship(person,role_type,{roles: collect(role) },movie) AS roles"
                       ^
```

Looking around at the docs, it seems I need to use a CALL here? I tried that and got:

```
Invalid input 'p': expected 'n/N' or 's/S' (line 11, column 29 (offset: 367))
"RETURN movie, person, call apoc.create.vRelationship(person,role_type,{roles: collect(role) },movie) AS roles"
                             ^
```

EDIT 3: after manually installing apoc, the VR technique looks to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)<-[r1:ACTED_IN|DIRECTED|PRODUCED]-(person:Person) 
WITH movie, r1, person

// unwind the list of roles and sort them per movie and person
UNWIND r1.roles AS role
WITH movie, person, role
ORDER BY role

// recombine the ordered roles
RETURN movie, person, collect(role) AS roles
ORDER BY size(roles) DESC, movie.title, person.name
```

In order to keep this as a Role entity after the list has been sorted I think there are a couple of ways you can go. YMMV

1. Keep the roles in order at storage. for his you could do a one time re-order and then when they are updated alsways make sure they are ordered before they are re-committed. For this data set since this is historical data it makes great sense.
2. Create a different entity
3. Use APOC to create a virtual relationship entity in your results

Update the storage example...

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)<-[r1:ACTED_IN|DIRECTED|PRODUCED]-(person:Person) 
WITH movie, r1, person

// unwind the list of roles and sort them per movie and person
// keep the original rel too
UNWIND r1.roles AS role
WITH movie, person, r1, role
ORDER BY role

// recombine the ordered roles and update the property
SET r1.roles = COLLECT(role)
```

Another entity example...

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)<-[r1:ACTED_IN|DIRECTED|PRODUCED]-(person:Person) 
WITH movie, r1, person

// unwind the list of roles and sort them per movie and person
UNWIND coalesce(r1.roles, [null]) AS role
WITH movie, person, role
ORDER BY role

// recombine the ordered roles
RETURN movie, person,  { roles: COLLECT(role) } AS roles
ORDER BY movie.title, roles, person.name
```

APOC Virtual Relationship Example...

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)<-[r1:ACTED_IN|DIRECTED|PRODUCED]-(person:Person) 
WITH movie, r1, person

// unwind the list of roles and sort them per movie and person
// keep the rel type too as we will re-use it
UNWIND coalesce(r1.roles, [null]) AS role
WITH movie, person, type(r1) AS role_type, role
ORDER BY role

// recombine the ordered roles
RETURN movie, person,  apoc.create.vRelationship(person,role_type,{roles: collect(role) },movie) AS roles
ORDER BY movie.title, roles, person.name
```

Comment: Hi Dave, updated the post again :). Thanks for the ongoing help!

Comment: I think one of the commands I ran, jacked up the DB... I'm reinitializing and trying again... stand by :).

Comment: Ok... so I re-inited the DB and the entity example doesn't bind in Spring. The VR example looks most promising, just getting the same syntax error on the apoc call, but it looks like the data is collecting this time...

Comment: Ok... some googling tells me I need to manually install apoc... take 4 lol...

Comment: Woohoo... ! the VR query works and binds to Spring entities! Thanks again for all your help!